gtsave_extra is not working properly? Does not save my file and export seems to take a screenshot of screen rather than save image
I am trying to save a gt_extras table and when I try to save it it either doesn't save or takes a screeenshot of part of my screen rather than save the image. The only thing that seems to work is exporting it as a web page. I am new to R-Studio so baby me please.
I click on export as an image and I put in all the nessecary info then it tells me it cant find the directory but saves the image anyways? But then the image is just a screenshot of only part of the screen?
I wish I could take a screenshot but I am working with sensitive stuff so I cant show it.
I have tried using export and I have tried the gtsave_extra function and nothing works.
